# Minecraft multiple data tag command help

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I am making an adventure map but it won't let me use multiple data tags.

The command I'm using is

```
/give blackbelt999 minecraft:stone_button 1 0 {display:{Name;"place on diamond block to begin"},{CanPlaceOn:"diamond_block}
```

But I keep getting this error message:

```
Data tag parsing failed: Expected non-empty key at:..."place on diamond block to begin"},<--[HERE]
```

what is wrong with this command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple problems with your command:

1) it's `Name:` and not `Name;`
2) you need to close the `display` tag before you can pu in the `CanPlaceOn` tag.
3) the `CanPlaceOn` tag expects a list (`[]`) of things, even if there is only one thing in that list.

Fixed command:

```
/give blackbelt999 minecraft:stone_button 1 0 {display:{Name:"place on diamond block to begin"},CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:diamond_block"]}
```